# Browser displays black "xxx took too long to respond" for 3 seconds then displays the expected page

Tags: https, http, angular

There are two apps A and B.

A is used to authenticate users and passes a token to B, B adds a cookie.

Something strange happens whenever the cookie expires or after a long period of time or hard browser reset.

WITHOUT FIDDLER:

User hits app A enters credentials and gets forwarded to app B. Right away, for three seconds, the browsers displays a black "xxx took too long to respond" error screen, then the default page is rendered "in-place" and replaces the error screen soon after. This occurs when the cookie has expired or after an extended amount of time has elapsed.

[image]

WITH FIDDLER: (SEE SESSIONS 61, 71 and 83)

When I perform the same scenario in fiddler, where I would expect the black "xxx took too long to respond" screen, I get the certificate error screen attached with the open lock icon. I dismiss that three times. While I am dismissing the ssl tunnel errors the default user page is rendering.

[image]

[image]

The correlation is about the same time the lock dialog(s) in fiddle is the same place I get the black browser error screen and the app seems to be loading in the background and then refreshes once fully loaded.

My thought is there is a https-->http request being "partially" blocked from A-->B as B is http only with no certs. The devs tell me they can't find a request being made that is https.

So, I can't figure out where the ssl tunnel is coming from (see screen capture). My thoughts are.

1. The devs missed something and one of the calls is http.
2. A network appliance is attempting to convert the call to https, though there are no url rewrites on the IIS server.

What would cause a black "xxx took too long to respond"  to render while the default page is loading? It feels like a scenario where the request was changed before it was fully read or something like that.

Comment: If possible, open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com so that all relevant data can be analyzed. I think without putting entries from IIS log files into the whole picture, the troubleshooting so far is off track. Wasting too much time on Fiddler is not really useful, as the issue with it is different from your original one.

Comment: `The devs tell me they can't find a request being made that is https.` there needs to be a correlated capture of all three ends presented. Presenting one side (the client user side) is not sufficient.

Comment: The devs were right. The request was coming over as http, however, the Browers attempted upgrade to https against a test site with an expired certificate seemed to be causing the error page to display. I would prefer that the browser ignore the invalid certificate and/or handle the redirect more gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a proper investigation, the incoming requests, although over http, had the Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: header set to 1. This in essence caused the following  events to occur in accordiance with HSTS or HTTP Strict Transport Security.

```
1. Initial http request results in a 307 - temporary redirect.
2. HSTS makes second https request.
    a. The ssl certificate had expired on the dev web server.
    b. It appears that HSTS catches the invalid certificate and issues another redirect, essentially downgrading to http.
3. Redirect to http successful.
```

**Solution: Add a valid ssl certificate binding to the website.**

The mystery is why did the browser render the stock "request took too long" error page prior to rendering the fallback to http response. Well, if the call chain is examined, one can see one of the redirects, which I am guessing is the upgrade to https, results in a (unknown) value for Time. Hovering over the record reveals the accompanying message - "The request cannot be shown here because the page that issued it unloaded". Perhaps the browser interprets that as a client disconnected or quit waiting for a response. (something internal escalates and requests ssl then browser determines the cert is bad and abandons request) falls back to a stock image error screen while the second redirect is underway to the successful http.

[image]

Another view of the attempted upgrade then downgrade.

[image]